# Angular2 project with angular-cli is not loading css files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Hi I'm using an angular2 project with angular-cli, angular2-material, angular2-firebase, the angular2-material library works fine, but I notice that the css  for example if you declare a css on the component level or on the src level which is style.css the browser does not get the classes when you inspect the  elements on the page, also does not work even if you call the css on the index.html, the only thing that works is a theme.scss declare in angular-cli.json but no other style, this is the versions that I'm using.

```
npm: '4.0.5',
node version v7.4.0

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.25.5
node: 7.4.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.3
@angular/compiler: 2.4.3
@angular/core: 2.4.3
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.1
@angular/forms: 2.4.3
@angular/http: 2.4.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.3
@angular/router: 3.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.3
```

Comment: Could you give a [mcve]? This is likely related to style encapsulation, but your description is extremely vague.

Comment: Most likely a path issue. It is hard to be of help without more information. Such as showing code where you call the css file as well as the project structure with the directories.

Comment: I did't do anything this is the only thing I did in app.component.css the project is totally fresh jus install angular-cli, material, firebase and just add the add some two css classses 

.wrap{
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: black;


}


.wrapmenu{
    flex: 1;

}

Comment: Did the same thing this morning and I'm getting an error with css-loader - module not found. I can understand that it's not finding some css module, but why? angluar-cli.json was not changed.

Answer (score 0):

to load css styles with webpack you should add 'style-loader' and 'css-loader' plugin to webpack and then webpack will automatically found and inject them to your page by importing them in your Component for example you could add it to appComponent.ts by doing this:

```
import '../assets/styles.css'
```

to add webpack config to your project with angular cli command you should run this:

```
ng eject
```